# Error when trying to use count and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT takes.semester, takes.sec_id, takes.course_id, instructor.name, COUNT(takes.ID) 
FROM takes 
INNER JOIN teaches 
ON takes.course_id = teaches.course_id AND takes.semester = teaches.semester AND takes.sec_id = teaches.sec_id AND takes.year = teaches.year 
INNER JOIN instructor 
ON instructor.ID = teaches.ID 
WHERE takes.year = 2019
GROUP BY takes.course_id
```

This gave me an error:

```
#1064 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated columnExpression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ...
```

How do I fix this? I'm using group by so to count the number of IDs, but this error popped up. I don't know how to fix this. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `GROUP BY ` belongs at the end of the query

Comment: I put it at the end of the query as well. It didn't work either

Comment: This is the error when I put it at the end: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated columnExpression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: You need to 1) move group by to the end and 2) include all of your non-aggregated columns in the group by or aggregate them (i.e., `group by takes.semester, takes.sec_id, takes.course_id, instructor.name`)

Comment: @Tom Bro you are a legend. It's sorted now. Thank you!

Comment: the error message is clear, all couln have to be in the GROUP BY or have an aggregation function

Comment: ...and lose the DISTINCT modifier.  Group By already creates distinct rows.

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the `GROUP BY` to the end of the query as well as include the non-aggregate columns in your `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT takes.semester, 
                takes.sec_id, 
                takes.course_id, 
                instructor.name, 
                COUNT(takes.ID) 
FROM takes 
INNER JOIN teaches 
  ON takes.course_id = teaches.course_id 
    AND takes.semester = teaches.semester 
    AND takes.sec_id = teaches.sec_id AND takes.year = teaches.year 
INNER JOIN instructor ON instructor.ID = teaches.ID 
WHERE takes.year = 2019
GROUP BY takes.semester, takes.sec_id, takes.course_id, instructor.name
```